# Is there any way to seed custom binding to already created injector in Guice?

Tags: dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

I have created Injector instance using Guice.create(modules). After creating an injector I want to add some bindings dynamically, so is it possible?

Comment: You can use child injectors. This means that you have another injector with extra bindings, but those bindings won't be present in your "parent" injector

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, yes, that might work, I will try it, thanks.